# Behavior of login shell vs. Linux, 'sh -c'

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I have a seemingly-valid command that works fine on Linux boxes but fails on OSX, and I would like to know why.

```
sudo su - validusername sh -c 'whoami'
```

On Linux, this will echo 'validusername' on the console.  OSX however, shows an error:

```
/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file
```

Is this an OSX particularity?  Or is it due to the fact that OSX uses bash 3.2, while our linux boxes are on bash 4.x?

EDIT: I figured out a workaround quickly (`sudo -u`), I am mainly interested in learning why this happened.  Thanks!

Comment: Never forget OSX is not a GNU but a BSD.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, my first encounter with OSX BSD grep taught me that lesson quickly!

Comment: BTW this has little to do with Bash, and more to do with the version(s) of `sudo` and `su` (GNU vs BSD). I'd point out that there is no reason to use `su` at all (in fact arguably you shouldn't is you have `sudo`) since switches in `sudo` can accommodate your needs perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sudo -su validusername sh -c 'whoami'
```

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
sudo su - username -c whoami
```

The `su` man page says

> ```
>  su [-] [-c class] [-flms] [login [args]]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If the optional args are provided on the command line, they are passed to
>        the login shell of the target login.  Note that all command line argu-
>        ments before the target login name are processed by su itself, everything
>        after the target login name gets passed to the login shell.

Comment: Which version of OS X? My `su` man page says nothing of the sort. `su [-] [-flm] [login [args]]` under Mavericks.

Comment: OK, "a" su man page. I don't have a mac handy, so I was looking at a BSD man page: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=su

Answer (score 0):

OK, to start with you don't need both 'su' and 'sudo' - just the 'su' will do. I also doubt under Linux that you have the 'sh' since the effect of the '-' is to run a login shell but what on earth the poor shell is attempting in your command with both is anybody's guess.

I live in a world where we remove `sudo` from our Linux boxes so I can't check if your command actually works.

Under both OS X and Linux the command `su - username -c 'whoami'` will echo username.

There are some differences between the 'su' and 'sudo' found on Linux and OS X but they are due to the differences between our laid back, West Coast, BSD version of Unix and the uptight, East Coast, AT&T derived Gnu utilities used in the average Linux distro rather than bash versions since neither is a bash builtin.